# Error when dealing with DispatcherTimer.Tick method

Tags: c#, uwp, timer, win-universal-app, dispatchertimer

I need a simple timer that prints the countdown in a TextBlock in my UWP app. I was suggested to use DispatcherTimer. That's my code.

```
private void MainButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(1000);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();

        }

        private int Seconds;
        private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, DispatcherTimer  e)
        {
            Seconds++;
            MainTextBlock.Text = Seconds.ToString();
        }
```

Anyway, I see this error and I cannot figure it out.
[image: Error]

Any help in finding a better solution for my needs is welcome, too.

Comment: `Tick` has `EventHandler<object>` type, it doesn't accept `DispatcherTimer  e` as argument

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pavel, I changed it to ```EventHandler e``` but I still have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit above `DispatcherTimer_Tick like` the following. You could press + = <kbd>Tab</kbd>  key to generate evet handle method automatically.

```
private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
   
}
```